# List Index Out Of Range Error on python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\transpositioncipher.py", line 17, in 
>       cipher.append(stringList[(x*result)+i])
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

I am making a Transposition Cipher to encrypt a string. I will be working on decryption later.

I have been running into this error with no luck of fixing it.
The output should be [f, u, o, r] if the input text is 'four'.

```
import math

stringToEnc = input("String to encrypt: ")
stringList = list(stringToEnc.replace(" ", ""))
letterCount = len(stringList)

encrypted = []
result = letterCount

for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(letterCount))+1):
        if letterCount % i == 0:
            result = i
            break
i = 0
while i != letterCount:
        for x in range(result):
                encrypted.append(stringList[(x*result)+i])
        i+=1

print(encrypted)
```

Comment: If you got an exception/error, post the [full exception details](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/). Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @AChampion I have edited the post to include the error. Can you please take a look?

Comment: surprisingly enough, when I ran it in the debugger, it really was an index which was out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the debugger, or add `print ((x*result) + i)` into the while loop, you will see that `print ((x*result) + i)` returns 4 on the 3rd iteration of the for loop. 4 is out of bounds for `stringList` which has a length of 4, but only the indexes 0,1,2,3.